how to sync postgress data base from a linux server to another
I have a server that contains a PostgreSQL DB and I want to synchronize it daily to another server just in case the source server crashes, so I want to automatically synchronize it  to the other server as a backup any help will be great-full.
I have tried searching for it a lot but i couldn't find a way to make it automatically as a script.

Replicating a database is not a useful backup.

As with most database engines there are numerous strategies that can be taken for backup and restore.  Replicating a database near "real time" is a pretty costly strategy if you are looking for a way to have a backup in case something catastrophic happens to your primary database instance.
I would suggest you read the following Postgres documentation regarding PostgresSQL: Backup and Restore

A replica is not a backup, these are two very different things to solve different problems.
